# Should there be a significant differential in wind velocity indoors vs outdoors in relation to Earth's rotating atmosphere?

Tags: velocity, rotation, coriolis-effect

What is the behavior of a rotating Earth's atmosphere indoors? Should there be any differences experienced between the atmosphere spinning in lockstep with the Earth outdoors vs. closed-off indoors?

I've asked [this same question](https://www.quora.com/notifications/collection?__filter__=&__nsrc__=2&__sncid__=2294755717) in Quora already but do not feel that the answers have been satisfactory (yet), so I'm somewhat escalating it to here. Thanks and hope it's not too remedial a question for this forum.

Comment: The first (and non trivial!) task is to define the problem properly. For example, should we assume the earth is a sphere, or (more realistically) a perfect ellipsoid because of the interaction of rotation and gravity? What about thermal effects and seasonal variations - a real planet loses heat by radiation symmetrically in all directions, but gains it in a nonuniform way from solar radiation. It would be reasonable to assume the atmosphere is an ideal gas, but what about viscosity? That's not meant to be a complete list of undefined parameters - just thoughts off the top of my head.

Comment: Of course the "real-world" answer is trivial - just stick your head outside the door of the room ;) Even ignoring the local short term instabilities that form "weather", look at the global pattern of "trade winds" at the surface, and high-level winds like the jet stream.

Comment: thanks for the responses. we accept that the earth's rotation is a given, that it is ~1040 mph at the equator and reducing to near-zero at the poles with gradation in-between. we also accept that the atmosphere is rotating in 'lockstep' with the earth, at the same speed at the earth's surface and increasing predictably with altitude due to the nature of a ~sphere. given these...givens, then the atmosphere is perpetually moving at a high rate of speed in the same direction as the earth is rotating. yes, this raises some questions, but i am mostly concerned with any differentials (in or outside)

Comment: and yes, it is a good point to make sure all terms and variables are properly accounted for. for my part, i'm assuming a perfect sphere, but i think that the variations within the entire 'packet' of the atmosphere, that these variations would not cancel each other out and remove what i would expect to be a powerful differential right at the doorway of any building. since this is not what we see of course, i'm just trying to get the best explanation.

Comment: perhaps i should have just started by using an airplane as an example? laminar flow of the entire atmosphere (well...it can also be viewed as a turbulent flow system, not sure), 'boxed' when the fuselage as sealed/doors closed AND when the craft is at rest > plane takes off and makes any course change that is other than east/west inline with the rotating earth, then lands and...what is expected with the local atmospheric conditions inside vs what is occurring outside?

all this to ask: what happens when you seal off a part of a flow? even if the chamber is moving within the overall flow?

Answer (score 0):

The atmosphere outdoors should be subject to a slightly [differential rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_rotation). Indoors, because of the boundary conditions and the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force), the atmosphere might be experiencing some very small internal motion, mostly rotation. I haven't thought about it much, so I'm not confident in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the response. i can appreciate that differential rotation would present between surface  level atmosphere and, say, right before the karman line, but not sure i'm quite catching the reference to differential rotation within a structure and outside. if we accept that the entire...packet of atmosphere is moving at the rate of earth's rotation, then i would expect boundary conditions to present at any doorway